# Call function on element generated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a snippet from a code that generates element and appends it to parent container:

```
                $('#container-game-mobile').append(
                   $('<div>', {
                     'class': 'game-card-mobile',
                     'data-action': actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]
                   })
                );
```

is it possible to call function on a generated div? I would assume something like:

```
                    $('#container-game-mobile').append(
                       $('<div>', {
                         'class': 'game-card-mobile',
                         'data-action': actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]
                       }).this(myFunction())
                    );
```

Comment: If you want to call a jquery method on element, then use instead: `$('<div>', {...}).appendTo('#container-game-mobile').myFunction();`

Comment: You might want to make this question clearer... What do you mean by *call function on generated div* ?

Comment: @LcSalazar basically the appended div should be passed in as a attribute of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $div = $('<div />', {class: 'game-card-mobile', 'data-action': actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]});
$('#container-game-mobile').append($div);
$div.myFunction();
```

To pass it as a parameter:

```
var $div = $('<div />', {class: 'game-card-mobile', 'data-action': actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]});
$('#container-game-mobile').append($div);
myFunction($div);
```

Comment: I think your snippets may be wrong... I didn't get the `.append($div)`. But I think that's what he wants.

Comment: Read the OP code, he is appending a div, but he wants to do something afterwards with that div...

Comment: It would be better to set method on jQuery prototype object ($.fn.myMethod) and then call it on matched set: `$div.myMethod();`. Because i guess OP wants to call some methods/pugins on this DIV otherwise not clear why he would need to pass it as function parameter